# Accessing file in PUT route Laravel

Tags: php, curl, laravel-4, put

I am building a `REST` API endpoint which looks like this: (In `Laravel 4.2`)

```
PUT /upload/{name}
```

Here is the `Route` in routes.php which is able to route the `PUT` request.

```
Route::put('/upload/{name}', 'UploadController@upload')
->where('name', '[a-zA-Z0-9]+');
```

Now, the content of this request must contain the file to be saved. I am using the following `curl` request to do a preliminary test of the endpoint.

```
curl -X PUT localhost/upload/filename -F filedata=@test.file
```

And this is how, the data is being read in `PHP`:

```
$blob = file_get_contents('php://input', 'r' );
```

This is not giving me the actual file rather giving me the whole HTTP request as raw text (expected that). I even tried `parse_str()` but did not work.

What is the way to use `curl` in both `CLI` and `PHP` to send PUT requests and receive them subsequently in `PHP`? I have always struggled with this one request type.

Comment: Have you tried access to your file by `Input::file`? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files

Comment: Isn't this for uploaded files?? But I want to access the file in request content.

Comment: Your file have to be uploaded to server before you can access it from request. They are saved in tmp folder, and `$POST['file']` or `Input::file` is a way you can access it.

Comment: But what I am demanding is I want the file in the `body` of the request.

Comment: Try `$blob = Request::getContent()`

Comment: @lukasgeiter And is the `curl` request used ok?

Comment: @activatedGeek Not sure, I'm not very good with curl...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lukasgeiter has correctly said in the comments above:
Here is the solution:

```
    use Request;   // needed in Laravel 5  
    $request = Request::instance();    // fetch the request instance
    $content = $request->getContent();   // get the raw content
```

I have verified the length of the content and it matches the file which was `PUT`.